# Ticks scaling - How to change the common factor multiplier to an offset value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, python, axis, ticks

I am plotting the following figure using Python and I obtain this render:

[image]

Here, Python is automatically adding an constant value offset (+9.192682e9) on the y axis to read more easily the data.

Now, I try to obtain the same render using tikz. However, when I plot the data, I obtain a flat curve.

[image]

Do you have solutions to change the multiplier factor (.10^9) to a constant value offset (+9.192682e9) as it is done in Python ?

Here is the basic tikz figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\definecolor{lightgray204}{RGB}{204,204,204}

\begin{axis}[
height=7cm,
legend cell align={left},
legend style={
  fill opacity=0.8,
  draw opacity=1,
  text opacity=1,
  at={(0.03,0.97)},
  anchor=north west,
  draw=lightgray204
},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
width=12cm,
x grid style={lightgray},
xlabel={Puissance laser ($\unit{\micro\watt}$)},
xlabel={b},
xmajorgrids,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={lightgray},
ylabel={Fréquence d'horloge ($\unit{\Hz}$)},
ylabel={a},
ymajorgrids,
ytick style={color=black},
]
\addplot [semithick, darkblue, mark=*, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
165 9192682374.87676
149.62 9192682355.34463
123.45 9192682316.82627
91 9192682257.36819
63.08 9192682193.09079
42.1 9192682136.36608
28.39 9192682100.67402
18.61 9192682071.54598
};
\addlegendentry{$P_{W}=-7 dBm$}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `\pgfplotsset{ymin=-4, ymax=17}` ( change thelimits, of course)between \begin{tikzpicture} and the \begin{axis}

Answer (score 1):

I was able to partly fill your request, but there are numeric problems associated with it.

Let me show my solution first (and notice, that I stripped it down to the most relevant parts for readability. You should do so for the MWE, too.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            clip = false,
        ]
        \addplot [
            only marks,
        ] table[
                x index = 0,
                y expr=\thisrowno{1}-9192682071.00000,
            ]{%
                165     9192682374.87676
                149.62  9192682355.34463
                123.45  9192682316.82627
                91      9192682257.36819
                63.08   9192682193.09079
                42.1    9192682136.36608
                28.39   9192682100.67402
                18.61   9192682071.54598
            };

        \node [
            % draw, % if you want to see the exact placement of the node, uncomment this
            inner sep = 0pt,
            anchor = south west,
        ] at (rel axis cs:0, 1) {\small +9.192682071e9};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compiles to:

[image: problematic data]

My solution uses the `y expr=<expression>` key of the table during `\addplot`, and manually subtracts the offset value.
Additionally, a node with the offset value is manually placed in the north west axis corner.

The **problem** that this output does not look at all like the data and screenshot you provided, lies in the provided data: The engine behind pgfplots can not handle these large numbers, and somehow seems to drop parts of it silently.

I do not know a way around this currently, but if someone else has ideas, they may expand on this partial answer.

If you happen to be in control over the data, and do not mind editing them outside TeX, that would be a quick and dirty solution, but I suspect you want to explicitly keep the original data, as is good practice.